# Several Tasks insight one Service

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I'm interested is there any was to run for example 7 Tasks insight one Service?

```
private final DataService service = new DataService();

    class DataService extends ScheduledService<Void>
    {
        @Override
        protected Task<Void> createTask()
        {
            return new Task<Void>()
            {
                @Override
                protected Void call() throws Exception
                {

                    // Several tasks


                    return null;
                }
            };
        }
    }
```

In my case I need to run the Tasks in parallel.

Comment: A `ScheduledService` is designed to execute a task periodically (i.e. once every x seconds). Is what you want to do to launch 7 parallel tasks once every x seconds?

Comment: @James_D Absolutely correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class DataService extends ScheduledService<Void>
{

    private int numTasks ;

    public DataService(int numTasks) {
        setExecutor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool(r -> {
            Thread t = new Thread(r);
            t.setDaemon(true);
            return t ;
        }));
        this.numTasks = numTasks ;
    }

    @Override
    protected Task<Void> createTask()
    {
        return new Task<Void>()
        {
            @Override
            protected Void call() throws Exception
            {

                // Several tasks
                for (int i = 0; i < numTasks ; i++) {
                    final int taskNumber = i ;
                    Runnable task = () -> {
                        // code to execute task taskNumber...
                    };
                    getExecutor().execute(task);
                }
                return null;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Note that the call method will return immediately (i.e. before the individual tasks have completed), and at that point the service will move into a "succeeded" state. If you want the `call()` method to wait for the individual tasks to complete, you can do something like:

```
class DataService extends ScheduledService<Void>
{
    private int numTasks ;

    private final ExecutorService exec = Executors.newCachedThreadPool(r -> {
            Thread t = new Thread(r);
            t.setDaemon(true);
            return t ;
        });

    public DataService(int numTasks) {
        setExecutor(exec);
        this.numTasks = numTasks ;
    }

    @Override
    protected Task<Void> createTask()
    {
        return new Task<Void>()
        {
            @Override
            protected Void call() throws Exception
            {

                // Several tasks
                List<Callable<Void>> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int i = 0; i < numTasks; i++) {
                    final int taskNumber = i ;
                    Callable<Void> task = () -> {
                        // code to execute task taskNumber...
                        return null ;
                    };
                    tasks.add(task);
                }

                exec.invokeAll(tasks);

                return null;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there any other solution where I can dynamically using variable to set the number of the Tasks?

Comment: Uh, yes, just create them in a `for` loop.